# Difference between web controls rendering and html table properties using ASP.NET

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I'm designing a website in ASP.NET and I want to build table with some text, textboxes and validators in it. The problem is that table looks different in Firefox and IE. Here is an example:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?224860e266.png

Here is the table code in ASP.NET:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="text-align: right; border-collapse: separate;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Nadawca:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNadawca" runat="server" Width="250px" BorderStyle="none"
                BackColor="#c1ae85"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Nadawca jest wymagany."
                ControlToValidate="TextBoxNadawca" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Adres e-mail:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMail" runat="server" Width="250px" BorderStyle="none" BackColor="#c1ae85"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="E-mail jest wymagany."
                ControlToValidate="TextBoxMail" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxMail"
                ErrorMessage="Nieprawidłowy format." ForeColor="Red" Style="position: absolute;
                top: 589px; left: 632px; width: 160px;" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Temat:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownTemat" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 0px;" Width="250px"
                BorderStyle="none" BackColor="#c1ae85">
                <asp:ListItem>Reklama w serwisie</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Pomysł na rozwój serwisu</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Chcę zostać moderatorem</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Prawa autorskie</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Banicja</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Błąd na stronie</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Inne</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Treść:
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTresc" runat="server" Height="150px" TextMode="MultiLine"
                Width="250px" BorderStyle="none" BackColor="#c1ae85"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Treść jest wymagana."
                ControlToValidate="TextBoxTresc" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Wyślij" OnClick="Button1_Click" Width="250px"
                BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#c1ae85" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: justify">
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advice,
Peter.

Comment: What looks diffrent? you prehaps have screens shots of both?

Comment: Did you try `border="0"` as an attribute to the `<table>` tag?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.Net, and is only a cross-browser CSS/display issue.

Answer (score 2):

When i remove your styling code

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="text-align: right; border-collapse: separate;">
```

to

```
<table align="center">
```

It shows same for IE, Firefox and Chrome. So if you want to style your table ill suggest you to try CSS

Answer (score 2):

Don't use tables for your layout, use CSS. The only time you should use tables is for tabular data. By using CSS here you can omit border-bottom where you are getting the double borders.